# Using xml attribute id in page url and on page

Tags: php, xml, arrays, simplexml

Im pulling in data about sports events via an xml feed, im using simplexml to do so. So far ive got a `foreach` loop that loops through all of the events and echos them out as a list of event names wrapped in `<a>` tags, pointing to a page **event.php?=id** (id is determined via the events attribute called id).

to do this im using

```
<?php
    $xml = simplexml_load_file("openbet_cdn.xml");
    foreach($xml->response->williamhill->class->type->market as $market) {
        $market_attributes = $market->attributes();
        printf("<a href=\"event.php?id=%s\">%s</a>\n", 
                    $market_attributes->id, 
                    $market_attributes->name);
    }
?>
```

the feed I'm using is http://whdn.williamhill.com/pricefeed/openbet_cdn?action=template&template=getHierarchyByMarketType&classId=5&marketSort=HH&filterBIR=N

What im having trouble with is on my page event.php i keep getting the first event in the xml feed displayed. To do this im using :

```
<?php 
  foreach ($xml->response->williamhill->class->type->market->participant as $participant) {   
  $participant_attributes = $participant->attributes();  

    echo "<tr>";
      // EVENT NAME
      echo "<td>";
        echo "<a href=".$market_attributes['url'].">";
        echo $participant_attributes['name'];//participants name
        echo "</a>";
      echo"</td>";

      //ODDS
      echo "<td>";
        echo $participant_attributes['odds'];
      echo "</td>"; 
    echo "</tr>";
  } 
?>
```

I can see why it is because im not referencing the id which is in the URL of the event page. But I'm not quite sure of how to do this, any idea how I can tackle this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to add an `if` within the loop so that you only target the event ID that matches the one in the querystring. A nested loop is also needed because you want to loop over each market to find the matching `id`, then loop over each of its participants.

```
  foreach ($xml->response->williamhill->class->type->market as $market) {   

    if($market->attributes()->id == $_GET['id']) {

        foreach($market->participant as $participant) {
            $participant_attributes = $participant->attributes();  

            echo "<tr>";
              // EVENT NAME
              echo "<td>";
                echo "<a href=".$market->attributes()->url.">";
                echo $participant_attributes['name'];//participants name
                echo "</a>";
              echo"</td>";

              //ODDS
              echo "<td>";
                echo $participant_attributes['odds'];
              echo "</td>"; 
            echo "</tr>";
        }

        break; // <-- we've found the target and echo'ed it so no need to keep looping
    }
  }
```

Comment: thanks for that, whats really weird is that if i change the IF statment to run the market attributes, rather than the participants attributes (and change the rest of the script in accordance), it works but running it on the participants attributes it dosnt echo anything out to the screen other than my header and footer which are php includes. any idea why that might be ?

Comment: My mistake - see my edit. You need a nested foreach (2 loops). The outer loop loops over the markets to find the one that matches the `id`, then the inner loop loops over each participant in the market.